# Fotorama - How to add inline style to the <div class="fotorama__stage__frame">?

Tags: fotorama

I would like to give there custom background for each image. Please let me know how to each div.fotorama__stage__frame? (must be inline, because every image will have different background)

Answer (score 0):

I will do this, but I do not know if it is the right answer...

Binding the "fotorama:show" event you have a opportunity to change the "fotorama__stage" class

```js
$('#yourLayerId').on(
  'fotorama:show',
  function (e, fotorama, extra) {
    $('.fotorama__stage').css('background-image', 'your background here');
  }
);
```

Hope this help,